# magento 2 add associate Simple Products with custom options to Configurable Product not working

Tags: magento2, product, catalog

I want to add the simple products with custom options to configurable product.When I am trying to add the simple product to configurable product, it's not showing after product save.Need suggestion to achieve this .
Basically it not updating into database once it assign it saved but not showing in configuration grid i think it some conditions based can any one tell me where i need to change that conditions

Answer (score 1):

After debugging i got the solution when we save product that time if custom options having in data base **catalog_product_entity** table **required_options** is updating as 1 if not having it updating as 0.
Based on this field configuration data filtering If you look in to this file you will get 
**public_html\vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Model\Product\Type\Configurable.php**

present code below function line number 1408 to 1411

```
private function getConfiguredUsedProductCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $skipStockFilter = true
    )

    $collection
                ->addAttributeToSelect($this->getAttributesForCollection($product))
                 ->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
                ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId());
```

i change like this

```
 $collection
            ->addAttributeToSelect($this->getAttributesForCollection($product))
             //->addFilterByRequiredOptions()
            ->setStoreId($product->getStoreId());
```

now working as i expected

Comment: We're trying to do something similar, how has this worked for you? Any issues?

Comment: @codestr no issues it working perfect